# Set the value of attr_accessor from inside Rspec test and FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I am using this Rails gem to add captcha question to my comment form. https://github.com/kiskolabs/humanizer

I am trying to bypass the captcha inside my Rspec test. According to documentation, this can be done by adding these code into my model

```
attr_accessor :bypass_humanizer
require_human_on :create, :unless => :bypass_humanizer
```

Now, I just need to know how to set the 'bypass_humanizer' attribute inside my test. This is what I have inside my test at the moment :

```
it 'saves the new comment in the database' do
    comment = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:comment, :bypass_humanizer => true)

    expect {
      post :create, blog_id: @blog, comment: comment
    }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

**-------- UPDATE --------**

Funny enough that I can do this in my another Rspec test and test will pass

```
hello = create(:comment, body: 'Hello World', bypass_humanizer: true)
```

So I just need to find something similar for FactoryGirl attributes_for

Comment: Try to compare what attributes you get when you use this form in Dev env and Test env

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I just updated the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding `bypass_humanizer true` in your FactoryGirl factory, so that every time you generate an instance of that class `bypass_humanizer` is set to true.

In alternative, you could write the test in this way:

```
it 'saves the new comment in the database' do
  comment = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:comment)
  comment.merge!(:bypass_humanizer => true)

  expect {
    post :create, blog_id: @blog, comment: comment
  }.to change(Comment, :count).by(1)
end
```

Comment: I just updated the question, might be able to give you new clue.

Comment: Add to your question the error messages and the contents of the various attributes_for hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that 'bypass_humanizer' is allowed in your controller and model.

If you're using strong_parameters, make sure that it's in the whitelist in the controller.

If you're using attr_accessible, make sure that it's listed appropriately.